# Transfer from one array to another

Tags: arrays, c

I have a loop that examines which numbers the passing parameter is divisible by. all numbers matching this condition are to be stored in another array. How do I set this up?

```
 #include <stdio.h>


void primfaktorzerlegung(int * zahl, int * ausgabe){

int array_primzahlen[] = {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97};
int length = sizeof(array_primzahlen)/sizeof(int);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

for(int k = 0; k<*zahl; k++){
    for( i = length; i>=0; i--){
        
        if(*zahl % array_primzahlen[i] == 0){
           *(ausgabe + j) = array_primzahlen[i];
            j++;
        *zahl = *zahl / array_primzahlen[i];
        
   
        }
        if(*zahl == 2){
            *(ausgabe + j) = array_primzahlen[i];
        }
    }
}
}


int main(void)
{
int ausgabe[10];
int zahl = 8;
primfaktorzerlegung(&zahl, ausgabe);

for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
printf("%d, ", ausgabe[i]);
 
}
return 0;
}
```

this is my current status. the "number" 8 is to be decomposed into its prime factors, i.e.: 2, 2, 2 and this also works, but completely different numbers are also stored in the array:

```
 2, 2, 2, 21883, 0, 0, -1385004928, 21883, 738867344, 32765
```

Comment: what did you try to do so far?

Comment: Do you mean something like `ausgabe[j++] = array_primzahlen[i];`? What is the expected behavior if `zahl` is divisible multiple times by the same prime number?

Comment: yes I tried it with a second loop for storing in ausgabe but it does not work so well

Comment: I did not propose a second loop. Please [edit] your question and show your attempted solution and explain what exactly you mean with "it does not work so well".

Comment: With `for( i = length; i>=0; i--)` you have UB (undefined behavior). You are starting at an index that is one _beyond_ the array end. You probably want: `for( i = length - 1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: Your formatting is all over the place. Please edit the post and fix the code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
void primfaktorzerlegung(int zahl, int * ausgabe){

    int array_primzahlen[] = 
        {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97};
    int length = sizeof(array_primzahlen)/sizeof(int);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for( i = length - 1; i>=0; i--){
        if(zahl % array_primzahlen[i] == 0){
        /*Here should be the transfer*/
            *(ausgabe + j) = array_primzahlen[i];
            j++;
        }

    }
}
```

I don't know if you want the numbers to be stored in reverse order or not. In that case, you could just reverse the array afterwards.

Comment: As a side comment, looking at the function name, I just realize that snake_case and CamelCase just don't need to exist in german. :-)